# Deployment error - dependent.class.invalid not found

Tags: deployment, ant, compile-error

I am deploying salesforce components using ANT and I am seeing this strange error and don't know what exactly it means by. I have included all the dependent components. Please let me know if anyone has seen this kind of error

> __MISSING LABEL__ PropertyFile - val dependent.class.invalid not found in section ContextExceptions Stack trace: null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have two things going on here, one which you can control and one which you cannot.

---

The one which you can control:

> dependent.class.invalid

Means that something you're trying to deploy won't compile in its current state. It'll probably take a little digging to figure out which class(es) are not able to be compiled in the target org.

---

The one you cannot control:

> __MISSING LABEL__ PropertyFile - val [IDENTIFIER] not found in section ContextExceptions Stack trace: null

This looks to be a message informing you that the label for that identifier couldn't be found. In your specific case that message usually says:

> Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation

There's a couple answers here on the site with useful information in troubleshooting which one of your classes won't compile, such as this one:

[How to troubleshoot 'Dependent class is invalid and needs > recompilation' exception?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/53665/660)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have one thing in my mind which I don't know if it's the solution or not. Actually I am deploying bitbucket branch to the new target environment using ant. If we deploy bitbucket branch we cannot deploy profiles. So while validating all these classes, there was no profile associated with all these new changes. If I deploy profile first, can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This error may cause because of your test class failure. Please execute all the test classes related to the deployment. And then try.

Thanks,