# Deployment Error while push to production

Tags: deployment

I have a urgent request while doing changes from sandbox to production i got the below errors.

**Change Set Error**

[image]

**Eclipse Error**

[image]

I have tried if any custom labels were used but no labels are used anywhere.

can somebody please help me to resolve the error?

Thanks,
Saravana

Comment: See duplicate q from last week: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197833/deployment-error-dependent-class-invalid-not-found

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue with the following method in Eclipse.

I have to insert test custom setting in the all my test classes when I deploy the test class to production using Eclipse, and then modify the apex classes.